# PostgreSQL roles lose permissions on tables after schema changes

Tags: postgresql, permissions, roles

We recently created new roles and users for our legacy Postgres DB.  We created base roles which the users inherit default permissions from on schema objects. It appears now when we make schema changes (DDL changes) we have to regrant permissions to the users that were already given access to the table/object. On a side note, the changes don't include foreign keys to tables that the user doesn't have permission too. Can anyone explain why we keep having to regrant permissions after DDL changes?

Thanks!

Comment: Nobody can tell you why without you providing an actual example of what you do and where it fails I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you @RichardHuxton. It fails when a consuming service with a limited user access try to access the table after a schema change. Would it help if I gave an example of the permissions associated with a user that fails ?